# Issue creating database tables using Symfony console

Tags: php, database, symfony

I'm trying to create the database tables using Symfony command's using the following line :

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

I obtain the following error :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

And it's the above class :

```php
namespace Cupon\TiendaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Tienda
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
   protected $id;

   /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad") */
   protected $ciudad;


   /**
   * Get id
   *
   * @return integer 
   */
   public function getId()
   {
     return $this->id;
   }    

   /**
    * Set ciudad
    *
    * @param \Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad $ciudad
    * @return Tienda
    */
   public function setCiudad(\Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad $ciudad = null)
   {
      $this->ciudad = $ciudad;
      return $this;
   }

   /**
   * Get ciudad
   *
   * @return \Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad 
   */
   public function getCiudad()
   {
      return $this->ciudad;
   }

   public function __toString()
   {
      return $this->getNombre();
   }

}
```

I don't understand whats really happen, because I put the ID for the class. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have an id set for `Cupon\CiudadBundle\Entity\Ciudad`

Comment: No, It would be generate it automatically isn't?

Comment: yes, if you generated the entity from the console. can you confirm that `Ciudad` has an `Id` field with `@ORM\Id` set

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the Ciudad Entity has an id

You should include the following annotations for example:

```
namespace Cupon\TiendaBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Ciudad 
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
   protected $id;
//..
```